# Add a mongo request into a file and archive this file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having some troubles while trying to use streams with a MongoDB request. I want to :

1. Get the results from a collection
2. Put this results into a file
3. Put this file into a CSV

I'm using the [archiver package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) for the file compression. The file contains csv formatted values, so for each row I have to parse them in the CSV format.

My function take a res (output) parameters, which means that I can send the result to a client directly. For the moment, I can put this results into a file without streams. I think I'll get memory troubles for a large amount of data that's why I want to use streams.

Here is my code (with no stream)

```
function getCSV(res,query) {

  <dbRequest>.toArray(function(err,docs){
    var csv = '';
    if(docs !== null){
        for(var i = 0; i< docs.length; i++){
            var line = '';

            for(var index in docs[i]){
                if(docs[i].hasOwnProperty(index) && (index !== '_id' ) ){

                    if(line !== '') line+= ',';

                    line += docs[i][index];
                }
            }

                console.log("line",line);

            csv += line += '\r\n';
        }

    }
}.bind(this));

    fileManager.addToFile(csv);

    archiver.initialize();
    archiver.addToArchive(fileManager.getName());
    fileManager.deleteFile();

    archiver.sendToClient(res);
};
```

Once the csv is completed, I had it to a file with a Filemanager Object. The latter one handles file creation and manipulation. The addToArchive method add the file to the current archive, and the sendToClient method send the archive through the output (res parameter is the function).

I'm using Express.js so I call this method with a server request.

Sometimes the file contains data, sometimes it is empty, could you explain me why ?
I'd like to understand how streams works, how could I implement this to my code ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you're having issue with the data sometimes showing up, but here is a way to send it with a stream. A couple of points of info before the code:

`.stream({transform: someFunction})`

takes a stream of documents from the database and runs whatever data manipulation you want on each document as it passes through the stream. I put this function into a closure to make it easier to keep the column headers, as well as allow you to pick and choose which keys from the document to use as columns. This will allow you to use it on different collections.

Here is the function that runs on each document as it passes through:

```
// this is a closure containing knowledge of the keys you want to use,
// as well as whether or not to add the headers before the current line
function createTransformFunction(keys) {

    var hasHeaders = false;

    // this is the function that is run on each document 
    // as it passes through the stream
    return function(document) {

        var values = [];
        var line;

        keys.forEach(function(key) {

            // explicitly use 'undefined'. 
            // if using !key, the number 0 would get replaced
            if (document[key] !== "undefined") {
                values.push(document[key]);
            }
            else {
                values.push("");
            }
        });

        // add the column headers only on the first document
        if (!hasHeaders) {
            line = keys.join(",") + "\r\n";
            line += values.join(",");
            hasHeaders = true;
        }
        else {
            // add the line breaks at the beginning of each line 
            // to avoid having an extra line at the end
            line = "\r\n";
            line += values.join(",");
        }
        // return the document to the stream and move on to the next one
        return line;
    }
}
```

You pass that function into the transform option for the database stream. Now assuming you have a collection of people with the keys `_id, firstName, lastName`:

```
function (req, res) {

    // create a transform function with the keys you want to keep
    var transformPerson = createTransformFunction(["firstName", "lastName"]);

    // Create the mongo read stream that uses your transform function
    var readStream = personCollection.find({}).stream({
        transform: transformPerson
    });

    // write stream to file
    var localWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream("./localFile.csv");
    readStream.pipe(localWriteStream);

    // write stream to download
    res.setHeader("content-type", "text/csv");
    res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=downloadFile.csv");
    readStream.pipe(res);
}
```

If you hit this endpoint, you'll trigger a download in the browser and write a local file. I didn't use archiver because I think it would add a level of complexity and take away from the concept of what's actually happening. The streams are all there, you'd just need to fiddle with it a bit to work it in with archiver.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution but the problem with files is that I'm restricted in terms of memory. The query might result up to 2 millions rows, and the file would be too big to be stored in the disk. That's why i'd like to use archiver to compress it. However, I did a stream with mongodb but the stream never ends. See http://jsfiddle.net/w273a1zn/ at line 5